# Compose ConstraintLayout image is offscreen with guidelines

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to compose, please explain

```
 ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val startImgGuideline = createGuidelineFromStart(0.17f)
        val endImgGuideline = createGuidelineFromEnd(0.83f)

            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = Icon.welcome),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .constrainAs(image) {
                        start.linkTo(startImgGuideline)
                        end.linkTo(endImgGuideline)
                        top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    }
                    .aspectRatio(1f)
            )
}
```

the idea is for image to have .17f of the screen from both sides , but image is halfway off the screen to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help. Change resources according to your needs.

```
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    val image = createRef()

    Image(
        imageVector = Icons.Filled.AccountBox,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(image) {
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                width = Dimension.percent(0.66f)
                height = Dimension.ratio("1:1")
            }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are misunderstanding the createGuidelineFromEnd(...)
This function counts from backwards. If you want to have the same boundaries you may use the same values (in both 0.17f)

Details to my Answer are inline with comments.

```
ConstraintLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            // this one is missing in your example - where is your image coming from?
            val image = createRef()

            val startImgGuideline = createGuidelineFromStart(0.17f)
            // we create the guideline from end...
            // counting backwards should fix this
            val endImgGuideline = createGuidelineFromEnd(0.17f)
    
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = Icon.welcome),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .constrainAs(image) {
                            start.linkTo(startImgGuideline)
                            end.linkTo(endImgGuideline)
                            top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        }
                        .aspectRatio(1f)
                )
    }
```